# JSON parse error on line 1 expecting Expecting '{', '['

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I've been trying to parse my data for a few days now and still have no clue how to get the results from my PHP array that is encoded by using json_encode. I am new to JQuery.

**this is not working:**

```
$.post('coordinate_array.php',{},function(data) {  //ERROR HERE EXPECTING SOMETHING??
 results = JSON.parse(data);
 for(i = 0;i < results.length;i++) {
  Paint(results[i].x, results[i].y);
 }
});
```

**I'm getting my data from this php file:**

```
<?php
include 'db_conn.php';

header('Content-Type: application/json'); //not sure if i need this here??

$coordinate_sql = "SELECT x_coord, y_coord FROM coordinates";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$coordinate_sql);

//see if query is good
if($result === false) {
    die(mysqli_error()); 
}

//array that will have number of desks in map area
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  

    //get desk array count      
    $desk[] = array('x' => $row['x_coord'], 
                                    'y' => $row['y_coord']);
} //end while loop
    echo json_encode($desk); //encode the array
?>
```

Comment: You're not showing anything, you need to do: `print(json_encode($desk));`. Also, `die(mysqli_error())` isn't JSON, so if something goes wrong it will be invalid JSON... You may also have an error somewhere else in your PHP file causing some notice (or whatever) being printed before the JSON.

Comment: And your error is? Only thing I can see is that you're not outputting your json data. `json_encode()` **RETURNS** the encoded string. it doesn't do output, so your script is effectively useless since nothing gets output to the client. You need `echo json_encode($desk)`

Comment: I added the echo and still nothing draws on screen.. this is the result I get to show you guys that my array does have values : [{"x":"20","y":"20"},{"x":"30","y":"30"},{"x":"40","y":"40"},{"x":"50","y":"50"}]  ... what can I be doing wrong in the JQuery??

Comment: @MarcB this is my error : Parse error on line 1:
$.post('coordinate_a
^
Expecting '{', '['

Comment: Why are you doing JSON.parse, data returned is an array, not a string to be parsed.

Comment: what am I supposed to use then? im new in jQuery @pln

Comment: Try results = data; and let us know

Comment: @pln still nothing.. this is frustrating lol.. am I supposed to add something in the squigly brackets when doing $.post?

Comment: You need to do some debugging. Use the development tools, set a breakpoint, look at the data being returned. Set a breakpoint in the js script and see what is received.

Answer (score 2):

You’re not `echo`ing your JSON data, so the page requested by the JS call will always be empty.
Use:

```
echo json_encode($desk);
```

at the end of your file.

Comment: @mario What is the result of this request? You should use a tool like `curl` to debug it, if not the Network tab in your browser.